# How to apply single material but to different and multiple objects?

Tags: materials

Probably a basic one, do you know how to apply once single material but on different objects?

1 material but multiple objects.

Thank you,
Waqas

Answer (score 3):

Put the material you want on one object that is the active object and while having ALL the objects you want the material on selected you press Ctrl+L (Make Links) and select "Materials".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question correctly but if I do then it's really simple...

1. Create a new material on an object
2. Select the second object
3. Switch to the material menu
4. Either create a new material slot first or directly click on the material icon left of the material name and select the material that you've already created on your first object in the material drop down menu.

That's it. You now have the same material applied to two different objects.
[image]

Comment: @iowaqas Also you should know that orphaned materials (materials with 0 objects using them) get discarded when you close the .blend unless you click the **F** button next to the material name to create a "fake user" to keep them. In the drop-down selection menu the number of users for each material is shown.